# Input, Output decorators as directive metadata

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to have the `@Input` and `@Output` directives as component metadata (instead of having them inside the component class). You can refer the below documentation link to see what I'm trying to achieve.

[Declaring Input and Output properties](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#declaring-input-and-output-properties)

However I'm receiving the below error while I'm trying to do so,

> Property 'deleteRequest' does not exist on type 'HeroComponent'.

Here is my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knuzbj) fiddle for reference.

Can someone shed light here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit the import and usage of `@Input/@Output` but you still have to declare a variable to use it.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xwkft)

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../app/hero'

@Component({
  inputs: ['hero'],
  outputs: ['deleteRequest'],
  selector: 'hero',
  template: 
  `
    <div>
      <pre>{{hero | json}}</pre>
      <button (click)="deleteRequestInit()">Get</button>
    </div>
  `
})

export class HeroComponent {

  public hero: Hero;
  public deleteRequest: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public deleteRequestInit(): void {
    this.deleteRequest.emit({'message': 'Are you sure you want to delete this record!.'})
  }
}
```

Comment: Happens to the best ;) it would be cool if you could mark as correct answer :)

Comment: Seems SO won't permit me to do that till another 5 more mins.. ;-)

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Done!.. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: @undefinedMayNotBeNull Looks like you lost an arm there!  Make sure you escape the backslash, `¯\\_(ツ)_/¯` = ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯